# Print precise value of pow() function in c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, pow, cmath

[image]my output is coming wrong. I guess i'm wrong with casting. please help me out.

```cpp
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    unsigned long long int a,s;
    cin>>a;
    s=(2*pow(10,n)+a);
```

But when I am giving large `n` like `17` or `18` then my output which is `s` is not coming as expected.
see image for output
e.g: when `n=17`, `a=67576676767676788` then `s=267576676767676800` which ideally should be  `2*10^17 + 67576676767676788`

Comment: If you are asking about C++, why tag the question with C?

Comment: What is the largest value that can be stored in a `long long int`?

Comment: @ScottHunter sir because pow() can be used in c as well as c++

Comment: there is an inflation of question incorrectly flagged as C. Why do you tag a language different from the one you are using?

Comment: `cin` is C++ not C. Answers differ depending on what language your write your code in

Comment: `pow` can be used in a lot of other languages, but you didn't tag them.

Comment: @ScottHunter i guess long long int can store upto 18 digits but I'm not very sure

Comment: Even if you can pass integer arguments to [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) it's still a floating-point function, with all the drawbacks that have (see e.g. [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)).

Comment: OK I removed 'C' tag please help me with C++

Comment: What happens when you try to display the "2*pow(10,n)"?

Comment: What do you mean by "not coming as expected"? You should show us the value of `s` that you got, so that we can see if you are just seeing a floating point issue or something more catastrophic.

Comment: If you change your last line to `auto s = (2 * powl(10, n) + a);` (and remove `s` declaration) it will work as you expect, just change cout precision to display it correctly.

Comment: You can solve the problem by writing a function to compute 10^n as an unsigned long long, e.g. `unsigned long long power10(int n) { unsigned long long result = 1; for (int i=0; i<n; i++){ result *= 10; } return result; }`

Comment: @user3386109 :)

Answer (score 8):

First you have to understand what is going on.

1. To be able to use [std::pow](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow), compiler silently converts integer types to `double` and returned value is a `double` too.
2. Note that `double` has 16 significant digits (in decimal representation).
3. When you do assignment, conversion of `double` to `long long int` is silently performed
4. `unsigned long long int` - if this type has 64 bits the maximum power of 10 is 19

Now if you want to exceed this limitation you should use an external library. `gmp` is quite nice.

If it is acceptable to have a limitation from range of `unsigned long long int` just implement your own power function.

Comment: Or use `long double`, although I do not know if it is is required or just "may be" bigger than double

Comment: @Hawky `sizeof(long double) >= sizeof(double)` per the standard so it may make no difference, and doesn't on winodws.

Comment: @NathanOliver I checked just now, sizeof(long double): msvc 8, gcc 16, clang 16.